# UIScrollView is not working / Error width and height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've `scrollView` and I inserted to my `scrollView` many objects, but my `scrollView` get me error it's width and height are (0.0)

**Code:**

```
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1200)
    scroll.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 244/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
    return scroll
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(scrollView.frame.size.height)
}

func setupScrollView() {

    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

}
```

When I changed width and height in constraint get me error!

What is the problem??

Comment: Try settings the `contentHeight` of your scrollview

Comment: First, element frames will ***not*** be correct in `viewDidLoad()`. Second, in the code you've shown, you are not calling `setupScrollView()`, so you won't even have a scrollview in your view, and of course it won't have a valid frame size. You also say:  *"I inserted to my scrollView many objects"* --- If you want help, you need to show the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As you are configuring constraints programmatically, make sure to add the below line before setting the constraints.

`scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: I added before in `anchor` extension